# "The entire stock" or "the whole stock"?

Tags: word-choice

> - She bought the **entire** stock of household goods in that store and left nothing.
> - She bought the **whole** stock of household goods in that store and left nothing.

Which one is more appropriate?

Can I use both?

Answer (score 2):

When talking about collections of objects; the **entire** can be used for collections of different objects. **Whole** is considered a collection of parts.

The expression “whole stock” considers stock to be a single unit that has not been subdivided. An “entire stock” means all different objects in stock. In this case either could be used.